# no serialized xml response when calling a php/cake web app

Tags: php, xml-serialization, cakephp

I've got a strange behavior in a web app written with PHP 5/cake running on centos.
The issue is this:
I'm calling an API to return XML formatted data from MySql.
If the total data size is small, all works fine.

But when the result includes thousands of data elements (pairs of timestamp/value) the xml serialize function fails to return the xml response. It actually looks like the thread died, maybe due to an exception?

Here's the code - this is **app/views/analytic/ajax.ctp**, after I got the data ok from the db:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
e('<?xml version="1.0"?>');

echo 'before serialize';
e($xml->serialize2($msg, array('format' => 'tags')));
echo 'after serialize';

e($this->element('sql_dump'));
```

?>

I don't see the 'after serialize' output.

$xml->serialize() is part of **cake/views/helpers/xml.php**

```
function serialize($data, $options = array()) {
$options += array('attributes' => false, 'format' => 'attributes');
$data =& new Xml($data, $options);
return $data->toString($options + array('header' => false));
}
```

it looks like this line is causing the problem:

```
$data =& new Xml($data, $options);
```

I've searched for this problem everywhere without any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thx

Ofer

Comment: problem solved - I increased the memory_limit in php.ini from 32M to 512M.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved - I increased the memory_limit in php.ini from 32M to 512M.